# Divisibility within a block of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I have solved the simpler case of this question (with just $a$ and $b$ and a $b$ length block), but no answer on this site has ever properly answered the generalisation:

Let $a,b,c \in \Bbb{N}.\space $Suppose $a<b<c$. Does every block of $c$ consecutive naturals contain three distinct naturals whose product is divisible by $abc$?

I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim is false, though constructing a counterexample is tricky.

Let $a = 77$, $b=91$, and $c=143$: these factor as $7\cdot11$, $7\cdot13$, and $11\cdot 13$, so $abc = 7^2\cdot 11^2\cdot 13^2$.

Over the interval $5930, 5931,\dots, 6072$ (which has length $143$), we have:

- only one number divisible by $7\cdot11$ or $7\cdot 13$ or $11\cdot 13$: it is $6006 = 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$.
- no multiples of $13^2$.

Since there are no multiples of $13^2$, the three numbers we pick must include two different multiples of $13$. Among them, $6006$ is the only one that can also contribute factors of $7$ or $11$. So after we've chosen the two multiples of $13$, our number is divisible by at most $7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13^2$, but not $7^2$ or $11^2$ - and that's if we use $6006$.

(If we decide not to use $6006$, then we're even more doomed: we have no factors of $7$ or $11$ at all, and no way to pick up all of them from the last number.)

That leaves us trying to pick up another factor of $7$ and another factor of $11$ from the third number chosen. But the only number divisible by both in this range is $6006$, which we've already picked.

---

The claim *is* true when $a$, $b$, and $c$ are pairwise relatively prime. In that case, we just find a multiple of $a$, a multiple of $b$, and a multiple of $c$ in the correct range, and pick them all. If a number is serving double duty in this regard that's fine; for example, when $a$ and $b$ have a factor in common, a multiple of $a$ and of $b$ is a multiple of $ab$. We can just choose an arbitrary number to fill out the trio.

Answer (score 0):

When I say "the claim", I refer to the statement "Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$ with $a < b < c$. Then every block of $c$ consecutive naturals contains three distinct naturals whose product is divisible by $abc$."

**Easy case.** I believe that the claim is true when $\frac ca \geq 2$ and $\frac cb \geq 2$. In this case, we have at least two $a$- and $b$-multiples that can "fit" within an arbitrary $c$-block. Let $a_1, a_2, ... a_n$ be the $a$-multiples in the $k$th $c$-block, and $b_1, b_2, ... b_n$ be the $b$-multiples in this block ($n \geq 2$ in this case).

If $a_i = b_j = ck$, then we choose $ck$ as our first number within the block. Under these circumstances, it is impossible for $a_{i-1} = b_{j-1}$, since $a \neq b$. So we can choose $a_{i-1}$ and  $b_{j-1}$ as our second and third numbers.

If $(a_x = ck) \oplus (b_y = ck)$ for some $x,y$, then we choose $ck$ as our first number within the block. Then, if there exists some $i,j$ for which $a_i = b_j$, then we choose $a_i$ as our second number and a leftover $b_q$ as the third (unless it was the case that $\exists y : b_y = ck$, in which case we choose $b_j$ as our second number and a leftover $a_q$ as the third).

If $a$-multiples and $b$-multiples never intersect in the block, then the claim is trivially true, assuming $\frac ca \geq 2$ and $\frac cb \geq 2$.

---

**Otherwise.** When the criteria for the easy case are not met, the claim is not always true. We see that we will be unable to find three distinct numbers when, for some $k$th $c$-block, the following criteria are fulfilled:

- There are exactly $2$ $a$-multiples in the $c$-block
- There is exactly $1$ $b$-multiple in the $c$-block
- $a_1 = b_1$
- $a_2 = ck$

An example ordered triplet $(a,b,c)$ exemplifying this case is $(3,4,5)$. With these values, the criteria that cause the claim to be false are achieved when

$$5 x = 3 y$$ $$3 (y - 1) = 4 z$$ is true for $x, y, z \in \mathbb{N}$ (we got these equations from the criteria for claim-failure).

A set of integer solutions to this system of equations is

$$x = 12 k + 3$$
$$y = 20 k + 5$$
$$z = 15 k + 3$$
$$k \in \mathbb{N}$$

(A consequence of this is that the claim fails an infinite number of times for these values of $a,b,c$.)

Let $k=1$, then we get $x=15$. **This means that for $(a,b,c) = (3,4,5)$, the $15$th $5$-block does not include 3 distinct integers whose product is divisible by $abc$.** Writing out the numbers in the block reveals that this is indeed the case:

$$a = 3: 71 \,\,\,\, \color{blue}{72} \,\,\,\, 73 \,\,\,\, 74 \,\,\,\, \color{blue}{75}$$

$$b = 4: 71 \,\,\,\, \color{green}{72} \,\,\,\, 73 \,\,\,\, 74 \,\,\,\, 75$$

$$c = 5: 71 \,\,\,\, 72 \,\,\,\, 73 \,\,\,\, 74 \,\,\,\, \color{red}{75}$$

Comment: I don't see how this is a counterexample. Pick any third number whatsoever, and you'll get the distinct integers you want; for example, $71 \cdot 72 \cdot 75$ is divisible by $3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Oh, you're right. For some reason I thought that the numbers would have to be multiples of $a, b, c$. Why isn't that the case? Also, what do you mean by "any third number"?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Wait, doesn't that mean that the claim is always true? Since for the $k$th $c$-block we can choose $ck$ in conjunction with $a_1$ and $b_1$, since $a < b < c$ guarantees that $\exists a_1, b_1$ between $(c-1)k+1$ and $ck$, inclusive?

Comment: I'm still somewhat skeptical about cases where $a,b,c$ share common factors. In that case, if we pick a number which is both a multiple of $a$ and $b$, then including it doesn't *necessarily* guarantee that the product is divisible by $ab$.